# why did mypy complains "object" not callable when using a TypedDict alias

Tags: python, mypy

I have file named `debug.py`:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class T(TypedDict):
    a: int


Q = T

x = Q(a=1)
```

when I run

```
mypy debug.py
```

I see

```
debug.py:9: error: "object" not callable
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

If I replace `x = Q(a=1)` with `x = T(a=1)`, then the complain would gone.

Using `reveal_type` shows

```
debug.py:9: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.object'
debug.py:10: note: Revealed type is 'def () -> debug.T'
```

Why aren't `Q` and `T` the same?

Comment: This seems like a bug.  In playing around with it I found that if you do `foo = Q = T` then all three are detected as the right type.